# jQuery Coda Slider

Tags: jquery, slider, coda

recently just tried to jump right into jQuery but found it to be harder than I expected.

I was trying to implement the Coda Slider 1.1.1 to my new layout. Somehow my cross-links are not causing the "slide effect" that should appear. The linking is working but without the effect.

See for yourself at http://www.origross.net/od/jquerycss/index.html

Help is very appreciated.

Best,
Ori

::::EDIT::::
Fixed the link.

Comment: Thanks! I must've been really tired.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little bit outdated, but look at [this tutorial](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/), it's exactly what you need ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an out of date version of Coda Slider as the script you've got on your site doesn't match the version from ndoherty.com.

Comment: Well I just updated the coda js file with a fresh downloaded one from Niall's site and now it seems to be even more messed up.

I intentionally removed the "tab" navigation (which shows up as a regular li now) since I wanted to use my own navigation.

Also, the coda js file I downloaded also only shows 1.1 in the context on the top and not 1.1.1.

Help anyone?